# Admin check function returns a wrong result

Tags: php, html, if-statement

So i am working on an arcade script and the first thing i decided to do was the login-signup system. Anyways, there are 2 sign up pages. One for the admin and one for the users. The admins will be hidden user another directory(Ex: admincp/signup.php). So when you register as a user, witch works all perfect fine. All the data getting works ect. When you register as a user it sets a row in the database named admin to 0. (The admin sign-up would set it to 1).

```
<?php 

    // Exeute the connection to the database
    require("common.php"); 

    // Is the user logged in?
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        // If the are not lets send em away
        header("Location: login.php"); 

        // We MUST do this. Or else people can view this page without logging it
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 
    function isAdmin($number)
    {
        if ($number = 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if ($number = 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if ($number > 1)
        {
            // adminTF is short for adminTrueFalse
            return "Invalid adminTF key";
        }
    }

?> 
Hello
<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>,
you have <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['coins'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
 coins and you are <?php
                        if (isAdmin(0) == true)
                        {
                            echo "an admin.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "not an admin.";
                        }
                    ?>
<br /> 
<a href="memberlist.php">Memberlist</a><br /> 
<a href="edit_account.php">Edit Account</a><br /> 
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Okay so when you read it you can tell it has a function that is supposed to tell me if the user is an admin or not. Because i am debugging, i just want it to tell me that i am not an admin. But even when i plug in zero for the required key, it still tells me i am an admin. Even though it is supposed to tell me that i am not one (because the number is zero), it says "you are an admin."

Comment: "Sorry for putting it another site, the whole code is relevant and this website wouldn't let me fit anymore text after it" - To my knowledge, StackOverflow doesn't have a character limit.

Comment: btw, your `isAdmin` function is pretty much a no-op. Just `if( $adminTF)` will do (where `$adminTF` is the variable containing the admin flag)

Comment: Update your question title to something that is relevant to your actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `=` (assignment operator) instead of `==` (comparison).

Comment: Thank you for your help mate. I cant believe i sat for 45 minutes reading it line by line and i never saw that. Thank your for the help :D @Alex